# How to scrape 'Click to Display' fields with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the number of schools and names of schools that basketball players get offers from verbalcommits.com

Using this page as an example: http://www.verbalcommits.com/players/jarrey-foster

It's easy to access the first offer (SMU) but all of the other offers are hidden behind the "Show other offers" button.  When I inspect the page, I can see the offers but my scraper doesn't get to them.  I've been using the following:

```
page=urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.verbalcommits.com/players/jarrey-foster") #opens page    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') #makes page into a BS python object
schools = soup.body.findAll('span',{"class":"team_name"})
print(schools)
```

This returns the first span that has the team name in it, but not the rest of the spans that are hidden.  What do I need to add to access the rest of the page that is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get other data because when you click button then JavaScript reads it from server from

http://www.verbalcommits.com/player_divs/closed_offers?player_id=17766&_=1475626846752

Now you can use this url with BS to get data.

I used `Firebug` in Firefox or `Developer Tools` in Chrome to find this url.

---

**EDIT:** inside HTML I found `data-player-id="17766"` - it is first argument in above url. Maybe you can find second argument so you could generate url using Python.

---

**EDIT:** I checked url

http://www.verbalcommits.com/player_divs/closed_offers?player_id=17766

and it gives the same data so you don't need second argument.

Comment: @Matthew Alternatively if you like clicking, look into `Selenium`

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate more on [@furas's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39863674/771848). Here is how you can extract the player id and make a second request to get the "closed offers". For this, we are going to maintain a web-scraping session with `requests`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get("http://www.verbalcommits.com/players/jarrey-foster")

    # get the player id
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    player_id = soup.select_one("h1.player-name").get("data-player-id")

    # get closed offers
    response = session.get("http://www.verbalcommits.com/player_divs/closed_offers", params={"player_id": player_id})

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # print team names
    for team in soup.select(".team_name"):
        print(team.get_text())
```

Prints team names for demonstration purposes:

```
UTEP
Sam Houston State
New Hampshire
Rice
Temple
Liberty
UL Lafayette
```